# TCP connection between Android app and visual studio terminal

Tags: android, visual-studio, tcp, communication

I’m trying to implement a tcp communication with my android app being the client side. The server has already been implemented in Visual Studio in c++ using the library `WS2tcpip.h`. The client side should then send a string for the server to receive and then return again. I’ve already tested the server with a client that was also implemented in Visual Studio, and I was able to send a message that the server received and then returned. See the image below

[TCP client and server communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prLkC.png)

**UPDATED CODE**

ControlFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false); //This inflates the control_fragment layout to this java class.

    startBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    socketString = view.findViewById(R.id.socketString);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask();
            b.execute("Hello");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String ip, message;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        ip = "192.168.87.103";
        message = params[0];
        try {
            s = new Socket(ip, 9700);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(message);
            dos.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: UnknownHostException" + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: IOexception" + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Exception" + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I see that the client is connected to the server after I have pressed the button but it disconnects immediately, as shown in the image below.

[TCP connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxifq.png)

I think the mistake is in the code below. It seems the server doesn't receive anything.

```
int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0); //Returns the number of bytes received
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Error in recv(). Qutting" << '\n' << endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    if (bytesReceived == 0)
    {
        cout << "Client disconnected " << '\n' << endl;
        break;
    }
```

I have already included internet permission in manifest. Hope that makes sense and thank you in advance.

Comment: `String message = voids[0];` That does tell us nothing. We dont know what you are sending. Please use a real text.

Comment: `socketString.getText().toString()` Here it starts. We know noting about what was typed. Or what socketstring would be.

Comment: If you could not connect then there is an IOException. Please post the relevant part from the logcat.

Comment: I did not receive any IOException when running. And what I'm trying to send is a String that user is typing from an EditText. Sry, but this is my first time trying to implement a TCP connection between an app and a Visual Studio terminal

Comment: That you are trying to send a string that the user types in is clear. Only we do not know what is typed in. So if you ask for help you could much better post code like `messageSender.execute("Now we know what you are doing");` But if you even cannot connect then it is irrelevant and you should have an exception of some kind.

Comment: I've updated the post from "UPDATED CODE" and downwards. Please know I'm doing my best to explain and to post the needed code. There is no need to be rude.

Comment: Who or what was rude? I'm pretty amazed.

Comment: The way you wrote that made it sound like you thought I was being purposefully dumb. But anyway, does it make sense now?

Comment: Nothing of that all. But a la.. `dos.writeUTF(message);` Dont send utf. Try `dos.write(message.getBytes());`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thank you very much. All though it still disconnects almost immediately, it now disconnects right when the message has been sent and received on the server side.  Is that due to calling these functions: `dos.close();  ` and `s.close();  ` on the client side?

Comment: Yes indeed. That closes the socket. Which is ok because if you left it open and doInBackground finished the connection would stay but you had to access to it.